# Turn a list of variable length into multiple lists

Tags: python, string, list

I am writing a script that takes user input of however many characters and I want to put each one of the characters into its own list to be then manipulated.

```
input = AVI
```

Output:

```
A = ['A'] V = ['V'] I = ['I']
```

I was able to get it into a single list like this: ['A','V','I'] but that becomes too confusing for what I want to do later.

Comment: Too confusing?  How do you expect to know what the variable names are for the lists you are going to create?

Comment: Also, what happens when the user enters a string with duplicate letters?

Comment: As to Stephen's point, if you know which letter you want to access, why not just hard-code that letter in directly instead of accessing a string with its value?

Answer (score 7):

Consider using `dict` with `enumerate`. Now you can even retrieve your letters by location.

```
x = input('Input a string:\n')
# User inputs 'AVI'

d = dict(enumerate(x))
# {0: 'A', 1: 'V', 2: 'I'}
```

I struggle to see how you know *which* letters to access when the user is inputting a string, so it doesn't make sense to name your variables (or, here, keys) after the letters themselves.

Answer (score 3):

If you really *want* to have a variable named after itself, Use a [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) thus:

```
>>> s='AVI'
>>> {e:e for e in s}
{'A': 'A', 'I': 'I', 'V': 'V'}
```

Then access it like so:

```
>>> di={e:e for e in s}
>>> di['A']
'A'
```

Or, enumerate for an index (thanks jpp):

```
>>> {n:e for n,e in enumerate(s)}
{0: 'A', 1: 'V', 2: 'I'}
```

Comment: Or `dict(enumerate(s))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a for loop and in the for write if-else conditions 
and for inserting any character that you want into your lists use appned() method.